# What are the issues and solution, regarding the looming U.S. Government shutdown at 12:01 am Sunday Oct 1st?

Tags: united-states, congress, government-shutdown

**Question:**

What are the issues and solution, regarding the looming U.S. Government shutdown (expected for 12:01 am Sun, Oct 1st 2023)?

**Background**

In the United States,  both branches of the bicameral legislature have a role in the passing of a budget. The House of Representatives( with 435 members ) and Senate (with 100 members ) both must agree on a Budget.  The process is each pass individual budget resolutions, then a consolidated budget is negotiated in a joint Senate and House committee.  Then both chambers have an up or down vote on the merged bill before they send it to the President to sign or veto.

If for any reason a budget is not passed,  It results in a government shutdown.  All non essential ( typically national security concerns ) are shut down.  This results in millions of federal workers furloughed, national parks shut,  Federal Services stopped.  Big mess and a lot of angry voters.

**Factors Framing the Impasse**

1. The Republican party(221 seats) narrow 5 seat majority over the Democratic Party(212 seats) in the U.S House of Represenatives.
2. A minority faction within the House majority who have blocked the house process for passing a budget resolution.
3. Every Congress passes it's own rules for how it will operate.  These rules usually are passed by the majority on a strict party vote.  A specific rule seem tangentially related to this impasse.

   - A.) any single republican member can force the current leader of the House (Speaker of the House) out of his leadership position, by issuing a move to vacate.  Given it took 15 rounds of votes for the Republicans to decide on this speaker,  this is a threat with teeth.  According to at lease one Republican member, this order to vacate would be used against GOP leadership if they passed either a bipartisan continuing resolution(short term spending bill to keep the government running),  or a bipartisan budget.

Which leaves us with the Question: What do these members want in exchange for supporting a new budget?  What is the solution, path to getting a new budget?

Comment: The House voted 335-91 to pass a continual resolution Sat Sept 31,  meeting the two-thirds threshold required, with 90 Republicans and one Democrat, Illinois Rep. Mike Quigley, opposed to the measure, arguing it lacked funding for Ukraine. So basically the Dems got off the bench and voted for a continual resolution joining the majority of republicans in the house.  Now comes the motion to vacate the speaker?

Answer (score 2):

IDK about solutions, but one issue, which some might have predicted given how hard it was for McCarthy to get his gavel despite the nominal majority of his party, is that the "hard-right" of the party rejected the spending bill he proposed, despite it making some cuts (that in turn made it a long shot in the D-controlled Senate).

According to some [earlier](https://thehill.com/homenews/house/4224799-gaetz-we-will-see-if-democrats-bail-out-our-failed-speaker/) newspaper (The Hill) reporting, Gaetz might see this moment as round n+1 of the aforementioned leadership election, where he might get a different result by cornering McCarthy:

> Rep. Matt Gaetz (R-Fla.) indicated Tuesday that he could force a vote on ousting House Speaker Kevin McCarthy (R-Calif.), suggesting the House will soon see if his Democratic colleagues “bail out our [its] failed Speaker.”
>
> “And the one thing I agree with my Democrat colleagues on is that for the last eight months, this House has been poorly led,” Gaetz said on the House floor Tuesday night. “And we own that, and we have to do something about it, and you know what? My Democratic colleagues will have an opportunity to do something about that too, and we will see if they bail out our failed Speaker.”
>
> Gaetz has repeatedly threatened to oust McCarthy from his Speakership role if he does not cave to a series of conservative demands on spending and legislation. [...]

As for the spending bills, color me confused, but that piece mentions that *four* had been considered, but others were still penging. Cutting most funding from Ukraine [seems](https://thehill.com/homenews/house/4224579-house-gop-advances-four-spending-bills-after-failed-attempts/) to have been a demand of TMG and probably others allied with her.

> McCarthy initially said he would remove the Ukraine aid from the Pentagon funding bill and hold a separate vote on it, but backtracked after recognizing that there was also assistance for Kyiv in the appropriations bill for the Department of State and foreign operations. The Speaker said it was “too difficult” to strip the money out of the State Department measure.
>
> Greene spoke out against the aid for Ukraine following the vote.
>
> “I just voted NO to advance Ukraine funding bills. After tonight, we will find out who is actually against sending YOUR money to Ukraine. No more stump speeches. No more red meat. No more chest thumping in letters,” Greene wrote in a post on X.
>
> The successful procedural vote marks an incremental win for McCarthy, who has struggled to advance spending measures this month amid conservative opposition. The House tried to advance the Department of Defense appropriations bill twice last week, with hard-line opposition sinking the measure both times.
>
> The advancement of the bills, however, will do nothing to avert a shutdown ahead of the Sept. 30 government funding deadline.
>
> Leaders in both parties and chambers have recognized that a continuing resolution will be needed to keep the lights on in Washington beyond the Saturday deadline, but the path to clearing such a measure is unclear.

So reading between the lines, at least one demand of the "hard right" is for the funding for Ukraine to be cut from the various budgets, before they vote anything else.

Earlier in the year (July) [some](https://www.businessinsider.in/politics/world/news/70-house-republicans-voted-to-cut-off-all-us-military-aid-to-ukraine/articleshow/101739996.cms) 70 Republicans led by Gaetz voted to cut off all military aid to Ukraine. I'm not convinced they'd all shut down the government over that, but more recently some 27 of the Freedom Caucus have sent McCarthy a letter (alas I can't seem to find the full text thereof) demanding, in Axios' [summary](https://www.axios.com/2023/09/28/house-freedom-caucus-mccarthy-shutdown-letter):

> for McCarthy to provide a "plan to address the public and widely reported issues threatening final passage of the four appropriations bills" in addition for a schedule on the five remaining bills that made it out of committee.
>
> The 27 lawmakers that signed on also requested information on when the House Appropriations Committee will mark up the two bills that remain in committee and answers on additional spending cuts.

Probably the first issue is the most salient, as it essentially asks how McCarthy is going to overcome the Senate objections to those bills, because

> Even if the House is able to complete their work on all 12 bills, they are likely dead on arrival in the Democrat-controlled upper chamber.

FWTW, as for solutions [according](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/09/29/politics/kevin-mccarthy-shutdown-latest/index.html) to CNN's take on McCarthy's sayings:

> In the aftermath of the failed vote [on his continuing resolution], McCarthy argued that aid to Ukraine should be dropped from a bipartisan stopgap bill in the Senate – though, given how little time remains, it is not clear that any kind of deal could be reached prior to a shutdown taking effect Saturday at midnight.
>
> “I think if we had a clean one without Ukraine on it, we could probably be able to move that through. I think if the Senate puts Ukraine on there and focuses on Ukraine over America, I think that could cause real problems,” he told CNN’s Manu Raju.
>
> [...]
>
> After the House failed to pass the stopgap bill, McCarthy told Republicans at a closed-door conference meeting there aren’t many options to avoid a shutdown, according to sources in room.
>
> He told his members they can either approve the GOP’s stopgap plan that failed, accept a Senate proposal, put a “clean” stopgap on the floor to dare Democrats to block it – or shut down the government. A large number of House Republicans have already vocally criticized the Senate proposal, making that unlikely to pass in the chamber.

But a number from the Freedom Caucus say they don't trust McCarthy to negotiate anything with Senate...

> GOP Rep. Ken Buck, who voted against the House GOP stopgap funding measure Friday, said the failed effort was a “no confidence vote” in McCarthy.
>
> “This was a vote where people didn’t have faith that Kevin McCarthy was going to do the right thing. We passed a vote on the debt ceiling. He went and negotiated a significantly higher number with President Biden. People don’t have faith that when it comes time to negotiate he’s going to do the right thing,” Buck told CNN’s Jake Tapper on “The Lead.”

Which is probably why they sent him the letter asking him to essentially lay out his plans for overcoming Senate objections to the House (high cuts) bills. (A form of backseat driving, if you ask me.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is even among the mainstream Freedom Caucus demands, but TMG also said earlier in the month she would [vote to] shut down the gov't without an impeachment hearing on Biden https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2023/sep/01/us-government-shutdown-marjorie-taylor-greene I see a hearing did take place https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2023/sep/28/biden-impeachment-hearing-house-republicans but I'm not sure if she was satisfied with that.

Comment: continuing resolution passed both House and Senate Sat Sept 30.  Two Bipartisan votes one in each chamber both getting majority support from Republicans and Democrats.  Matt Gates has said he will move to remove Kevin from the speaker ship this week.